# Transactions isolation level and locking records, disable SELECT on records that are in running transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Can I **disable `SELECT`** on rows that are been used inside of a transaction?

For example, rows in table *potatoes* are being destroyed in transaction 1, and it takes a long time to do so. In transaction 2, there is `SELECT*` on the *potatoes* table. I don't want to select those records that are being used in transaction 1.

So, the result for `SELECT*` potatoes is without the records that are being used in transaction 1.

Is **isolation level serializable** right fit for transaction 1, so transaction 2 can't select those rows?
Or I need to lock those records with some **lock mode**?

I'm trying to avoid flags in the database or Redis.

Things I found:

- [**Transaction levels** in Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-transaction)
- [Transaction levels in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html)
- [**Pessimistic locking** in Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange requirement. Logically, the potatoes are not deleted until your transaction completes – after all, you can still roll back the transaction, and then it has never happened. What is important is the *logical order* of transactions, and normally there is nothing wrong with assuming that the transaction that selected the potatoes happened logically *before* the deleting transaction.

All that said, if you still insist on your requirement, here's how you can do it:

The deleting transaction simply deletes potatoes using `DELETE`, but you use a modified query to select potatoes:

```
SELECT /* whatever */
FROM potatoes
WHERE /* condition */
FOR SHARE OF potatoes SKIP LOCKED;
```

Different from a regular `SELECT`, this query will place a `SHARE` lock on each row selected. Such locks don't conflict with each other, so several such queries can select the same potatoes.

However, the lock will conflict with the `EXCLUSIVE` row lock of the `DELETE`, so it cannot select such rows. To avoid blocking when such a row is encountered, you add `SKIP LOCKED` as in my example.

All this is not for free: a row lock modifies the table row, so such queries will cause writes as well as reads.

Comment: I don't want to expose to the user those records that are being deleted. The user will ask himself, why do I see these records if I deleted them? Or worse, edit/restore those records while deleting is still running. 
Do you maybe have an example of select with share lock in Rails ORM?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Rails. In the deleting transaction the rows will not be visible, but I guess your queries are running in another transaction. If someone tries to modify a row that is being deleted, that modification will block and wait until the transaction is done. If you cannot make the deleting transaction short (which would be best), perhaps you could inform the user that the potatoes are being deleted, then the user won't be surprised if they don't disappear immediately.

Comment: Problem is that I have a transaction that is recursively deleting records. In that transaction, child objects are being deleted and then self (potato). That's why I want to lock potato explicitly and then skip locked. You helped me. 
One more question, what downsides are of SHARE lock on my records?

Comment: As I wrote: like any other row lock, it will be stored in the table row itself, so it will modify the row and dirty the data block that contains it. These dirty blocks have to be written to disk by the next checkpoint, so you will experience more writing I/O with share locks (even from purely reading queries).

Comment: Oh, hidden fields `xmax` and `xmin` are written as the query is done. I see. Thank you.

Comment: [Only `xmax`](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/whats-in-an-xmax/), but yes.

Comment: what about aggregating functions? I tried to use count() for pagination on lock records and I can't. It's not so obvious for me that that is not possible. Do you have any idea?

Comment: That depends on the precise statement you are using. Maybe open another question for that.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539909/behavior-of-share-locked-records-why-are-aggregation-functions-impossible