# Behavior of SHARE locked records, why are aggregation functions impossible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

On the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513053/transactions-isolation-level-and-locking-records-disable-select-on-records-that/58516097?noredirect=1#comment103401076_58516097), I asked about how can I exclude records from `SELECT` that are locked with `UPDATE` lock.

It is not so obvious for me that on records that are locked with `SHARE LOCK` is not possible to make aggregation functions.

Why is that, and how can I bypass this problem?

---

The process that I'm making:

1. Lock records that are in the queue for delete with `UPDATE` lock
2. To exclude that records for user, on `SELECT set SHARE lock` that will have a conflict with execute `UPDATE lock`, and filter that records
3. Paginate that selected records (`COUNT()` is being used)

Is my only option to **set flag** in dB/Redis to filter that records?

---

Error I'm getting:

```
PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  FOR SHARE is not allowed with aggregate functions
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "groups" WHERE (groups.deleted_at IS NULL) FOR SHARE OF groups SKIP LOCKED
```

Comment: `count()` should work just fine with share locks. Can you show the exact SQL statement you are using? What do you mean with "is not possible"? Can you describe the observed behavior in more detail and say how that differs from what you expect?

Comment: I edited my question. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subselect can help you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT 1
      FROM groups
      WHERE groups.deleted_at IS NULL
      FOR SHARE SKIP LOCKED) AS q;
```

The reason for this is that the query that locks the rows must be able to identify the row that is to be locked from the result.

`src/backend/optimizer/plan/planner.c` has this code comment:

```c
/*
 * We've got trouble if FOR [KEY] UPDATE/SHARE appears inside
 * grouping, since grouping renders a reference to individual tuple
 * CTIDs invalid.  This is also checked at parse time, but that's
 * insufficient because of rule substitution, query pullup, etc.
 */
```

So one could say that this is required by the way it is implemented.

Comment: That helps a lot, but I don't get it why does it need to be subquery?